# How do I bind data from Telerik ComboBox to my data model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-mvc

Why won't my Telerik ComboBoxFor bind my value and fill my ComboBox via AJAX?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Telerik().ComboBoxFor(model => model.VendorId)
        .Name("ddlVendor")
        .ClientEvents(events =>
                          {
                              events.OnLoad("onVendorLoad");
                              //events.OnChange("onVendorChange");
                              events.OnDataBinding("onComboBoxDataBinding");
                          }
        )
        .DataBinding(bind => bind.Ajax().Select("_AjaxGetVendors", "Car"))
    )
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Зберегти" />
    </p>
</fieldset>}
```

In my controller I get entity but VendorId == 0.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Car obj)
    {
            dm.InsertModel(obj);
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**

Remove `.Name("ddlVendor")` from your ComboBox if you don't need it.

**Option 2**

Rename your ComboBox as follows and update any client event references to the control:

```
.Name("VendorId")
```

Comment: Combobox data not filtered by Id. my Controller take Model entity: public ActionResult Create(Car obj)... and Car.VendorId always equils 0.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood your question. So your combo binds correctly but when you submit the form to create the record, your VendorId value on the model is empty?

Comment: Could you update your question with your controller code please?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if this resolves it for you.

Comment: Related: http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendoui-comboboxfor-doesn-t-bind-on-post#OZH12epDbUWEEfcUw0gGLA